# How can I use irb the Ruby interpreter to test/debug my .rb files?

Tags: ruby, debugging, interpreter, prompt, irb

How can I use irb the Ruby interpreter to test/debug my `.rb` files? I want to load an `.rb` file, let it run, and after it ends, get back to the irb prompt so I would be able to manipulate the variables which my script has built.

I tried `load`, `require`, and `irb -r`, but none of them worked as I would like. After the execution, when the program terminates, I get an irb prompt, but all of the variables are inaccessible. What can I do?

Comment: When I paste the content of my .rb file from the clipboard I got error message, because my .rb file is too big, lot of lines of code, or maybe it contains some illegal charachter. But it works flawlessly when I invoke with "ruby myscript.rb"

Comment: Currently I use this method: first I paste the first half of the code, and after the execution I paste the second half of the code from the clipboard into the IRB, this works, but it is very annoying...

Answer (score 2):

Not sure exactly what you want to do, but it sounds like you may want to use the "pry" gem instead.

Answer (score 2):

1. Install the `pry` gem see: http://pryrepl.org
2. require 'pry' at the start of your program.
3. put `binding.pry` at the end of your program (or where you want to start the interactive session)
4. run your program.

Using pry you will have all your variables in scope.

More information see the link above, and here:

http://banisterfiend.wordpress.com/2011/01/27/turning-irb-on-its-head-with-pry/

and:

https://github.com/pry/pry/wiki/Runtime-invocation

Answer (score 0):

If the variables you want are local variables, I do not think there is a way you can access them from another file.

If you just want the return value of the whole code that is on a different file, you can `eval` the whole content of that file within the main code and access the return value. You can access multiple values by putting them in an array or a hash at the end of the file to be `eval`ed.

Answer (score 0):

Add following code in place where you want irb to start

```
require 'irb'
IRB.start(__FILE__)
```

Answer (score 0):

### **`binding.irb`**

As of Ruby 2.4, placing this in your code will drop you into an irb session in the scope where it is placed.

No additional gem installs or require statements are needed.